# Configure Slim to run in user account

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, slim, mod-userdir

I'm having trouble getting Slim to run in my user account on the university's web server.  I'm pretty sure I'm just missing a step in my `.htaccess` file.

I have placed my Slim application in `/home/smithj/public_html/CS371/MySlimApp`

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /~smithj/CS371/MySlimApp/public/index.php [L]
```

Requests to the app are correctly being redirected to `index.php`; but, only the root route works.  I added a default handler and I see that the path given to the router begins with the root of my user account instead of the root of the app.  Specifically, when trying to access `http://www.mega.edu/~smithj/CS371/MySlimApp/public/testMe`, `$request->getURI()->getPath()` is `/~smithj/CS371/MySlimApp/public/testMe` instead of just `/testMe` as expected.

What else do I need to do to correctly configure the root of the app?

Comment: Why `/~smithj` and not `/home/smithj` or just nothing?

Comment: The web server is configured so that our personal web pages go in `/home/smithj/public_html`.  For example, the url `http://www.mega.edu/~smithj/cv.html` returns the file `/home/smithj/public_html/cv.html`.  I put `/~smithj/` in the `.htaccess` file instead of `/home/smithj/public_html` because that's what almost worked.  Using `/home/smithj/public_html/CS371/MySlimApp/public/index.php` caused a redirect to the main university web page for some reason.

Comment: A `RewriteRule` redirection can be either external (in which case you provide a full URL, including protocol and host name) or internal (in which case you provide a filesystem location). I don't think your `.htaccess` needs to mention `~smithj` at all.

Comment: What would a rule look like that doesn't mention `~smithj`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try the default template, `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`, with the `.htaccess` file located in the `public` folder?

Comment: When I make that change, the .htaccess file doesn't seem to have any effect (but, I don't understand why).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145632/discussion-between-zack-and-alvaro-gonzalez).